# Cucumber JS - Selecting part or all of a sentence

Tags: javascript, regex, cucumber

I am trying to define a reusable step which contains the same logic but may be worded differently. For example:

`the message "Running defect detection module..." should be displayed`

`the message "Defect detection complete." should be displayed when the process is complete`

My regex so far looks like this:

`/^the message "([^"]*)" should be displayed$/`

and I have also tried doing the following regex:

`/^the message "([^"]*)" should be displayed(\s*\w*)*$/`

But I am getting no results. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Remove `$`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lAi67K/1).

Comment: Sorry @WiktorStribiżew when I say it may be worded differently I am on about the 'when the process is complete' ending

Comment: Well, maybe [`^the message "([^"]*)" should be displayed(.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/lAi67K/2)?

Comment: The issue wasn't the issue in the end. When I was defining my step I forgot to put my second parameter as the second regex pattern so the callback function was actually not defined. The following regex worked in the end - /^the message "([^"]*)" should be displayed(\s*\w*)*$/ - Thank you for your help :)!

Comment: You seem to mention your code, but you have not shared it. Your post is off-topic then.

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```js
function check(str) {
  return /^the message \"(.*)\" should be displayed(.*)$/.test(str);
}

function test(str) {
  console.log(str, " => ", check(str));
}

test("the message \"Running defect detection module...\" should be displayed");
test("the message \"Defect detection complete.\" should be displayed when the process is complete");
```

Comment: This `.*` is too greedy and will match [like this, too](https://regex101.com/r/7ZIjz5/1).

Comment: My problem wasn't to do with the regex in the end it was a mistake I made on my part! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not trying to create such steps. Instead give the message a name (which encapsulates what it is trying to communicate) and write a step for each one

e.g.

Then 'I should see the defect detection is running'
Then 'I should see the defect detection is complete'

Cucumber is not great for testing precisely what appears in the UI. The idea is to use what appears in the UI to confirm that a certain business behaviour works, and to do this in such a way that the scenario doesn't fail every time you change a small detail (e.g the message starts with a capital, or has some punctuation added, or you use some cool graphic to show the defect detection is running).

Using regex's to create complex steps to match a range of scenario content is an anti-pattern. When I started cuking about 10 years ago I used regex's in every step definition, now I just don't use them at all.